# Cakephp 2.3.7 Url Rewriting is not properly configured on your server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.3

I am having a little trouble spinning up my web application. When I try to access my application I see URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. After doing my due diligence I read that Cakephp Devs decided to check the state of URL writing by checking access to Cake.Generic.css. That said, I have check that file and all my htaccess files, and everything seems to be ok to me. I might be wrong though. Below is what my htaccess files look like. Also I tried to hide the message by adding

```
url-rewriting-warning {
display:none;
}
```

but it didnt work. Also I have checked my httpd.conf files and the # has been removed from mod_rewrite. Here are my htaccess files.

Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

App/Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

App/Webroot/Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated!!Thanks!!

Comment: Silly suggestion: Did you restart Apache ?
If cake.generic.css can not be found (hence the warning is displayed) where did you define the url-rewriting-warning above ?
Also: I would add a line in one of those .htaccess files with "rubbish" in it to ensure that you get an error in the Apache when accessing the page, thus confirming those files are actually read and used.

Comment: Yes I have. Im going to try to add something to see if I can throw an error.

Comment: The URL Rewriting is defined in home.ctp. That said, I have been looking for a fix for 24 hours, and Im at the point where I want to pull my hair out!! There has to be a solution for this that is common knowledge to someone!

Comment: home.ctp does not define anything. Simply, if the style sheet can not be loaded, that paragraph/div becomes visible. Can you confirm mod_rewrite is working for the (virtual) host where the app is sitting ? Did apache throw an error after the test above ?

Comment: Well I added some rubbish to the Cake root htaccess file and I received the 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: I am sorry... I should have specified it earlier but... was the 'rubbish' inside the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ?
What happens if you enter the URL:

<url_to_your_site>/css/cake.generic.css

Comment: Yes it was in those tags. When I tried to access the CSS File from my URL it displayed the content inside the file which is....#url-rewriting-warning {
    display:none;
}

Comment: I added that to the CSS file....because I was told it could hide the URL Rewriting message in the header.

Comment: Sure, but hiding the style won't make mod_rewrite work. Besides the warning, are any of your scripts working ?
Also: do you actually read cake.generic.css in View/Layouts/default.ctp ?

Comment: I meant 'hiding the warning'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem!! I re-downloaded Cakephp 2.3.7 again..copied the Cake.Generic file..and pasted it back in the webroot folder...then I opened my text editor and added the following the default.ctp file..

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
```

It was smooth sailing from there. Thanks for the help Savedario!